How to Fetch Stream of a specific page from a document using GroupDocs.Viewer 20.8 in c#
Hello I am currently using GroupDocs.Viewer 19.6 Version in one of my utility and now I planned to upgrade it to GroupDocs.Viewer 20.8. I had a code where I am Fetching a page as a stream using GroupDocs.Viewer and I am working with that stream.
I am sharing my code for the reference.
ViewerConfig config = GetConfigurations();
ViewerImageHandler imageHandler = new ViewerImageHandler(config);


//using here
mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
imageOptions.PageNumber = pageIndex + 1;
var pages = imageHandler.GetPages(mStream, imageOptions);
pages[0].Stream.CopyTo(pageStream);

pageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

I am not able to find anything about how can I fetch a page in a stream using GroupDocs Viewer 20.8.

What do you mean by "Stream of a page", exactly? Also, what file-format is this? PDF? Doc? DocX? OpenDoc?

This particular code is to work with multi page images like tif, tiff and unsearchable pdf's.

In GroupDocs.Viewer 20.8, API changes might affect stream handling. Check updated documentation for new methods or configurations for fetching pages.

Yup but I did not find any solutions in documentations
